# string formatting for python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

In older version of python, 'str' object has no attribute 'format error will be resulted if i try to format string. params consists of something like `[u'name', '12']`. How to do the following in % string formatting?

```
def str(params):
    ......
    if params:
       msg_str = msg_str.format(*params)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the list to a tuple and pass it as the format argument:

```
msg_str = msg_str % tuple(params)
```

Example:

```
>>> lst = [123, 456]
>>> 'foo %d bar %d' % tuple(lst)
'foo 123 bar 456'
```

---

Note, it **must** be a tuple, passing the list directly won't work:

```
>>> 'foo %d bar %d' % lst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

Answer (score 3):

In this simple case

```
>>> "{0} {1}.".format(*("Hello", "world"))
'Hello world.'
```

You can just change the msg_str to the old style

```
>>> "%s %s."%(("Hello", "world"))
'Hello world.'
```

However, format has quite a few capabilities beyond that. There is no straight forward way to translate this one

```
>>> "{1} {0}.".format(*("world", "Hello"))
'Hello world.'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the % operator to interpolate values into a format string

```
>>> "%(foo)s %(bar)d" % {'bar': 42, 'foo': "spam"}
'spam 42'
```

Comment: Please do not indent your non-code text. Syntax highlighting plain text doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
msg_str = msg_str % tuple(params)
```

Comment: According to his question it's a list so he needs to convert it to a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Use string module available in Python 2.5

```
import string
tmp=string.Template("Hello ${name} !")
print tmp.safe_substitute(name="John")
```